# Taking Words/Or Arguements from a string in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So what I want to do with my bot is basically take words from a user and pass it in the command as arguments when the arguments are seperated by a $ sign. For example, if the user types cat$dog$cute, the program should take 'cat' , 'dog' and 'cute' as the arguments.

````
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const settings = {
  prefix:'suk!',
}
module.exports = {
    name:'booru',
     description:'this is a picture command',
     execute(client,message){
      const args = message.content.slice(settings.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
        const Booru = require('booru')
        const tags1 = args.slice(0, args.indexOf("$"));
        const tags2 = args.slice(0, args.indexof("$"));
        Booru.search('gelbooru', [`${tags1}`, `${tags2}`], { limit: 1, random: true })
          .then(posts => {
            for (let post of posts)
            embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`Aqua`)
            .setColor("RED")
            .setImage(post.fileUrl)  
            message.channel.send(embed1)
          })
        // or (using alias support and creating boorus)
     }
}
``` this code is like a reference
````

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way of doing that:

```js
let tags = args.map(arg => arg.split("$")).flat()
```

Given, for example,

```
const args = ["cat$dog$cute", "hey$world"];
```

this will produce the result of

```
["cat", "dog", "cute", "hey", "world"]
```

---

If instead you only wanted to split a single one of the arguments into tags, simply use string.split

```
let arg = args[0];
let tags = arg.split("$");
```